# Undefined symbols for architecture - strange message

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, makefile

When I compile I get a set of strange errors. 
This is what i compile with first. (This is generated from my makeFile.)

```
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic -c error.c -o error.o
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic -c agent.c -o agent.o
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic -c io.c -o io.o
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic -c map.c -o map.o
```

Then it comes down to linking it all together with my handler; I use this:

```
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic error.o agent.o io.o map.o handler.c -o handler
```

and it outputs a message that I cant find info about. Any ideas?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_m", referenced from:
    _print_map in io.o
    _read_map in io.o
    _check_row in map.o
    _get_start_pos in map.o
    _move_one_step in map.o
    _displayMoveOnMap in map.o
    _reset_map in map.o
    ...
    (maybe you meant: _reset_map, _move_one_step , _print_map , _read_map , _main )
```

I think it's just a little Makefile tweak but I can't find much on these errors.

Comment: Are print_map(), read_map() etc your code? Looks like a missing object file.

Comment: @John3136 yeah they are all in my code. declared in the headers ect I thought i was linking them up to the handler ?

Comment: How did you write so much code without testing it?

Comment: Please don't add "[SOLVED]" to the title of your question. That's indicated simply by accepting an answer (which you've done).

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Cheers @KeithThompson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got an `extern m` (I don't know what type, or even if it is a function) in both io.c and map.c, but not defining it anywhere. I'd look for the extern declaration in `map.h`, although that's just a guess.

Comment: Hi it was this problem and then it came up to a duplicate declaration warning, did abit of searching and for some reason i was declaring a struct NULL in the header. Thank you so much @rici